# How can I decide which python I will open in mac terminal?

Tags: python, macos, terminal

I have several two python on my mac, one is original, and another is downloaded on the website, when I open the python in terminal, how can I decide which I'm opening? Thanks for help.

Comment: use the full path, if you want a certain one always then edit your .bashrc or equivalent file and export the path

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Specify the full path to the binary.

```
$ some/path/to/python
 ...
>>>
```

Alternatively, create an alias to do so.

```
$ alias pythonx="some/path/to/python"
$ pythonx
 ...
>>>
```

Comment: so, there is no way to go to my downloaded version of python by just typing the python?

Comment: You don't want to override the system Python if you don't know what you're doing.

Answer (score 0):

I would recomend you to use *virtual environments*. Since you isolate your development environment, you are free of guilt of breaking something that is using the default Python version. Also, you can use whatever version of Python you want just by calling `python` from the console, after activating the *virtualenv* for that project.

See http://docs.python-guide.org/en/latest/dev/virtualenvs/ in order to understand how to use it.

Here [Use different Python version with virtualenv](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1534210/use-different-python-version-with-virtualenv) there is an explanation about how to change the Python's version for a specific environment.

Answer (score 0):

Also, if you just need to know which installation of Python is the system using, the way to do it is typing `which python` at the terminal.